# Using ajax/jQuery to update a list on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to create a dynamic list on a webpage based on user entry *without* refreshing the page each time.

For instance, a user would:

1. type a word into a textbox
2. click a button
3. the word would show up somewhere else on the page
4. the word would be erased from the textbox

Any new word typed would automatically be written underneath any previously entered words.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know anything about Ajax?. If you want only to point to a direction I see you already know it(ajax). Check on google about it.

Comment: Honest comment - the problem with questions like this is, if you learned how to use ajax, and how to track a click on a button you would know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="target"><div>

<input type="text" id="newInput" />
<input type="button" id="saveInput" />

<script>
// when button is pressed:
$('#saveInput').on('click', function(){
    // check if something is there
    if( $('#newInput').val().length !==0){
        $('#target').append('<div>'+ $('#newInput').val()+'</div>'); //append to a target
        $('#newInput').val(''); // empty input
        $('#newInput').focus() // for bonuspoint, place cursor back in input
    }
});
</script>
```

If you want each new entry as first listitem, use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) instead of [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: +1 for the bonus point and saying how to add item to front of list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an working example:

Html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtWord"/>
<input type="button" id="btnAddWord" value="Add new word" />

<ul id="words">
</ul>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnAddWord').bind('click', function(){
        if( $('#txtWord').val() !== ""){
            $('#words').append('<li>'+ $('#txtWord').val()+'</li>');
            $('#txtWord').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/AfNgH/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Somebody beat you to the punch though in terms of accepting an answer